# How do I get the value of the selected items in the multiselect bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-multiselect

I have already visited several similar topics, but the answers are always `$('element').val()`, but this only returns an array with the text and not the value. Note that I want it to return something like: `[1, 2, 3]` and not `[email1@email.com, email2@email.com, email3@email.com]`

```js
function create_multiselect(element){
    element.multiselect({
      enableFiltering: true,
      includeSelectAllOption: true,
      enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
      buttonWidth: '100%',
      maxHeight: 450,
  });
}
function getvalue(element){
  console.log(element.val());
}

$("#btn").on("click", function(){
  getvalue($("#activity_from"));
});

create_multiselect($('#activity_from'));
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- multiselect -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" integrity="sha512-EvvoSMXERW4Pe9LjDN9XDzHd66p8Z49gcrB7LCUplh0GcEHiV816gXGwIhir6PJiwl0ew8GFM2QaIg2TW02B9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js" integrity="sha512-aFvi2oPv3NjnjQv1Y/hmKD7RNMendo4CZ2DwQqMWzoURKxcqAoktj0nNG4LU8m23+Ws9X5uVDD4OXLqpUVXD5Q==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <select id="activity_from" name="multiselect[]" multiple="multiple" class="form-control activity_multiselect">
          <option valeu="1">email1@emal.com</option>
          <option valeu="2">email2@emal.com</option>
          <option valeu="3">email3@emal.com</option>
          </select>
</div>
                     
<button type="button" id="btn"> GET VALUE </button>
```

Comment: Change --valeu="1"-- for value="1"

Comment: @LuiscYm omg, that was so stupid of me, thanks, I will test it;

Comment: Don't worry, it happens often.